# Why does G-d reward reshaim in this world to punish them in the next, if He is good?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, reward-punishment, olam-haba-world-to-come, evil-resha

The question of "Why do some reshaim people live a good life, while some good people suffer" is often answered that G-d rewards the rasha in this world, in order to punish him in the world to come for all his sins.

How can we reconcile this with the concept that G-d is essentially good and that everything He does is for the good [of every individual] (as it says, for instance, "Tov Hashem lakol vrachamov al kol maasov"). Now, being rewarded in this world in order to be punished in the world to come surely seems like *not* a good thing for the rasha (in an absolute good sense). So why would G-d do that?

Comment: Citing a source that God rewards them now to punish them later, would improve the question.

Comment: "An empty-headed man cannot know, nor does a fool understand this: When the wicked bloom like grass, and all the evildoers blossom— it is so that they may be destroyed forever." - Psalm 92

Comment: citing a source that everything G-d does is for the good *of every individual* would also improve the question

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi See Tehillim 145 *Tov Hahsem Lakol...* - G-d is good to everybody.

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi I cited the source DanF mentioned in my original question.

Comment: I fail to understand the question.... If someone is determined to live a life that leads to gehennom, Hashem would be Kinder if He let the person be miserable in this life too? Isn't it better than such a person at least get the reward he did earn while he still can?

Comment: @Micha : From the case of tzadikim (who are punished in this world so that they won't have to be punished in the world to come) it seems apparent that it's better to be punished in this world than in olam haba. So then similarly it would seem to be kinder to punish the rasha in this world, to minimize his punishment in the world to come.

Comment: You said it yourself. G-d does what’s best for each individual.

Comment: I feel like all of these questions ultimately boil down to Ki Lo machshevosai machshevoseichem - the human mind is incapable of understanding Hashem’s ways.

Comment: what about Hashem gaurds all his lovers and the rishaim he destroys?

Comment: I heard a rabbi say (regarding a similar issue) these are for the good of the rasha, to persuade him to repent from his ways.  In midrash eicha rabba 1:31 (or 1:30 in some citations) Rav Zakok is worried that Vespasian's doctors should be paid in this world so he will not sit with them in the Next World. This indicates that the honor/presence/reward of rishaim in the Next world is painful or upsetting to the tzadikkim there. (This might be

Comment: @DonielF : Saying that the human mind is incapable of understanding G-d's ways seems to me to be cop out. The question was on how to reconcile two seemingly contradictory pesukim/themes. The pesukim and their commonly accepted interpretations are making definite statements about what G-d's ways are. If we couldn't at all understand G-d's ways, no such (or any other) statements could be possible.

Comment: Are we sure that most, let alone all reshaim live a “good life” and that tzaddikim suffer?

Answer (score 3):

In order to answer why God would do it we have to explain why we think He shouldn't do it. I assume that the reason why you (and probably most others) feel that He shouldn't do it is that you feel that reward in this world and reward in the next world are not equal. That being the case, we can ask the question more directly:

Let the designated reward for a mitzvah = X. If the threshold of X can be attained in this world then what is the difference whether a rasha receives it in this world or the next world? Either way he gets X. If the threshold of X cannot be reached in this world, then how can any good he receives in this world cancel out his reward in the next world? He earned X and he still hasn't gotten it!

Instead of asking **why** **God would** do it, we are really asking **how God could** do it.

The Chofetz Chaim actually answers both of these questions (separately, and makes no connection between them) although I don't think that either answer really suffices.

**First, the answer to why:**

He explains with a parable of a house on fire with all the valuables cast outside. Normally valuables are kept inside the house, but when there is a fire the valuables have to be cast outside so they don't get destroyed. Similarly, mitzvos are normally kept in the next world. But when a rasha commits sins, it is like lighting the house on fire, and the mitzvos have to be cast outside, i.e. to this world. Thus God rewards the rasha in this world.

**שם עולם חלק שני שער ההתחזקות פרק ד**

> והנה ליראיו הצפין הקב"ה טובתם לעולם הבא אבל אלו שנסוגים מאחרי ה' נותן
>   להם בעולם הזה עבור איזה מצוה שעשו ונבאר סיבת הדבר בדרך משל אחד שאמר
>   לרעהו הנה נשמע שיש שריפה בעיר נבוא לגביר פלוני קרובי להציל רכושו מן
>   האש ויהי בבואם לחצרו מצאו שכל כלי הבית היקרים כגון מורה השעות הטוב
>   והארגז עם התכשיטים הושלכו לחצר ויכה כף על כף יאמר לו מה ראית רען תאמר
>   לו מאץ באו הכלים היקרים האלו לפה והלא דרכם להיות בהיכל הפנימי אלא ודאי
>   ששם שלטה האש בקירותיו והושלכו לפה להציל לכל הפחות את התכשיטים וכן הדבר
>   בעניננו לכלל ישראל יש להם טרקלין למעלה ומכל תורה ומצות שמקיימים נבראים
>   מהן כמה מיני עידון ותענוג ומזומנים שם בטרקלין בשביל המקיימן שיתעדן שם
>   כשימלאו ימיו וכמו שכתוב צדיק כתמר יפרח וגו' שתילים בבית ה' וגו' אבל
>   האנשים שפרקו מעל עצמם עול מלכות שמים כבר נשרף ונתקלקל הטרקלין שלהם
>   למעלה וממילא המעט מצות שעשו בקטנותם כגון מצות מילה וכדומה הושלכו לחוץ
>   לפרוזדור שהוא העולם הזה שיתעדנו מהן

This doesn't really explain why God set up the system this way, nor does it address how God is "cheating" the rasha out of his full reward.

**The answer to how:**

This too is explained by a parable. A hundred counterfeit monetary documents are only worth one real monetary document. A real document containing the King's seal can be redeemed in the king's treasury, for a full sum of money, whereas a counterfeit document can only be redeemed for a few pennies on the black market. Similarly, mitzvos done lishmah carry the seal of God. They can be redeemed in the king's treasury (the next world). Mitzvos done by reshaim are not lishmah, and thus do not have God's seal. As counterfeit mitzvos, they can only be redeemed in the black market (this world) at a fraction of the value.

**שם עולם חלק ראשון שער שמירת השבת פרק ה**

> עוד נראה לי לבאר כוונה עמוקה בזה המאמר שיהיה תפוס בידו מה שלמד כדי שלא
>   השיגנו בושה וכלימה ליום הדין והוא בהקדם מה ששמעתי בשם גאון אחד שלפיכך
>   אין נותנין שכר המצות בעולם הזה מפני שבעולם הזה אין מקום לעריכת השולחן
>   לעושי המצות שהלא יפה שעה אחת של קורת רוח בעולם הבא מכל היי העולם הוה
>   והקשיתי אם כן איך יצוייר מה שאמר הכתוב ומשלם לשונאיו אל פניו להאבידו
>   דהיינו שמשלם להם שכר צדקתם בעולם הזה וכפירוש רש"י שם והתרגוסן והלא אין
>   מקום לתשלומין פה ונראה לי לבאר בדרך משל איש אחד רמאי פיתה קצין אחד
>   שיקנה מאתו מאה שטרות מזוייפים שוייף שטרי המלך וכאשר נתן לו הקצין מחירם
>   כנגדם שטר אהד אמיתי שאל אותו הלא אנכי נתתי לך מאה שטרות ואתה פוטרני
>   באחד השיב לו הוי סבל התדמה מעותיך למעותי הלא שלך מזויפים אבל שטרי הוא
>   אמת ויען אותו הרמאי מאי נפקא מיניה זה נייר וזה נייר השיב לו הוי פתי
>   ושוטה הלא שטרי אני יכול להובילו לאוצר המלך לפורטו שם בכל מטבע שארצה
>   ויקבלו אותי בסבר פנים יפות אבל שטרותיך המזויפים אם אכניס אותם לשם
>   יכירו מיד את הזיוף שאין שם המלך חתום עליהם ואתחייב ראשי למלך ולא אוכל
>   להוציאם כי אם בחורים וסדקים ואינם שוים כי אם איזה פרוטות כן הדבר ממש
>   בענייננו המצות אשה עם ה' עושים בודאי הם עושים אותם מפני רצון השם יתברך
>   שצוה אותם על זה ובודאי חתום השם יתברך על ענין זה כמו שאמרו חז"ל במד"ר
>   רות פ"ה כשאדם עושה מצוה אליהו כותבה ומלך המשיח והקב"ה חותם על ידיהם
>   הדא הוא דכתיב אז נדברו יראי ה' איש אל רעהו וגו' ויכתב ספר זכרון לפניו
>   וגו' וכעין רמז לזה יש גם כן בתורה שכתוב על כמה מצות בסופן אני ה ודרשו
>   על זה אני ה' נאמן לשלם שכר והוא כעין חתימה שחותם המלך על שטרותיו ובשטר
>   כזה אם יובא למעלה בודאי תיכף ישולם שנרו בכבוד גדול ויפה שעה אחת של
>   קורת רוח בעולם הבא מכל חיי העולם הזה ובודאי אין מקום לתשלומי שטר כזה
>   פה וכנ"ל אבל לא כן מי שהוא רשע מסתמא מצותיו המעטות שחם לה לא עוטה
>   לכבוד השם יתברך כלל ורק לאתה פניה וכבוד ובודאי אין שם השם יתברך חתום
>   על מצוה כזו והוא כשטר מזויף שאין המלה התום עליו וכשיובא לעולם האמת שטר
>   כזה אין שוה כלום ואדרבה יתעורר עליו רוגזו של המלך על שטרות כאלו ועל זה
>   אמרתי בדרך רמז מה דאיתא באבות פרק ראשון הוא היה אומר אם אין אני לי מי
>   לי רוצה לומר אם שמו של הקב"ה שהוא אני כמו שפירש"י בסוכה דף ס"ה שהוא
>   אחד מע"ב שמות אם אינו חתום על מצותי מי מהמלאכים יוכל לעשות לי שום טובה
>   ואמר עוד וכשאני לעצמי מה אני רוצה לומר אם הקב"ה יביט רק על עצמי ולא
>   יצרף לי זכות אבות מה אני חשוב במעשי אך מפני גודל טובו וחסדו של הקג"ה
>   אינו מקפח שכר כל בריה ואפילו של אדם רשע לכן גם לו ישולם שכר אך מקום
>   התשלומין בעבורם הוא בעלמא דשיקרא מפני שנעשו בשקר ומירמה ולכן יש גבול
>   לתשלומין וזהו שאמר המדרש שיראה האדם שיוכל לתפוס מה שלמד גידו שלא
>   יתבייש להראותו לפני פמליא של מעלה בשעה שיאמרו לו עמוד וערוך מקרא שקרית
>   וערוך משנה ששנית והיינו דאם לימודו יהיה לשם קינטור או לאיזה פניה דאם
>   לומד סתמא גם כן טוב הוא דסתמא לשמה קאי בודאי תשיגנו בושה וכלימה
>   בהראותו שם את סחורותיו אלו הנבזות

(The Chofetz Chaim reiterates this in Nidchei Yisrael Chapter 38.)

To me it sounds like this is just a way of saying that a rasha's mitzvah is actually worth less, and is not good enough to earn reward in the next world, because it is not done lishmah. But if a rasha did actually do a mitzvah lishmah then he would not receive its reward in this world, because in that case he would not be receiving the correct reward. In other words, it is not that God goes out of his way to hurt reshaim by giving them reward in this world; it is simply that for the most part their mitzvos are only worth reward in this world.

Comment: Rav Dessler I believe writes similarly in Volume I, around page 100. Bli neder when I have access to one I'll double check.

Comment: It's page 95. See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60599/the-wicked-rewarded-here-seemingly-arent-rewarded-in-full-fair

Answer (score 1):

the rasha has no business in the next world. he is unfit to derive enjoyment there. So might as well give him some good here.

Comment: Source? [15 characters]

Comment: @mevaqesh מי שלא טרח בערב שבת, מהיכן יאכל בשבת? It is not "lo yochal":" he won't eat", as a punition; it is "mheichan yochal":" from where should he eat?", as a consequence (heard from R Moshe Kaufman). +1